# Rewriting URL path with Nginx, no redirect

Tags: http, nginx, docker, proxy, url-rewriting

Say we have url `http://example.com/blog/posts` and we want to use Nginx to serve as a forward proxy, directing that request to a backend that will only see that url as `http://example.com/my-blog/foo/posts`.

How is this possible with nginx, no redirects and totally transparent to the backend?

We have the following so far:

```
rewrite ^/blog/(.*)$ /my-blog/foo$ last;
```

Currently our logs show the following:

`*1 "^(.*)$" matches "/blog/posts"`

`*1 rewritten data: "/my-blog/foo/posts"`

`GET /blog/posts HTTP/1.1" 404`

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example of what should work for you

```
location = /blog/posts {
  return 301 /my-blog/foo/posts;
}
```

Comment: No, thats a redirect. "How is this possible with nginx, no redirects"